# Decorator Pattern with multiple generics

Tags: java, generics, decorator

I am currently doing some code refactoring. So I came up replacing an existing `inheritance` design by a `decorator` design. But I am struggling with multiple generics (maybe it is simply not possible).

[image: Decorator implementation]

I have the above design at the moment. There is the `IConstraint` which `check`s a class against an implemented constraint. The concrete realization of those constraints are `SimpleConstraintA` and `SimpleConstraintB` both of them are checking some values from `ClassA`. The `Decorator` enhances the constraints e.g. there are some constraints which should not be checked when a specified value is not in range. `ClassA` implements the interfaces `IA` and `IB` so that`DecoratorA` and `DecoratorB` can work with it.

The usage of the design is as followed:

```
Test classToCheck = new Test("test");
IConstraint<Test> constraint = new DecoratorA<>(new DecoratorB<>(new SimpleConstraint()));
boolean value = constraint.check(classToCheck);
```

So what I want is to use the code with a different number of input parameters and different types. Like:

```
Test classToCheckA = new Test("testA");
Test classToCheckB = new Test("testB");

IConstraint<Test> constraint = new DecoratorA<>(new DecoratorB<>(new SimpleConstraint()));
boolean value = constraint.check(classToCheckA, classToCheckB);
```

Or:

```
Test classToCheckA = new Test("testA");
// TestB does implement the same interfaces as Test
TestB classToCheckB = new TestB("testB");

IConstraint<Test> constraint = new DecoratorA<>(new DecoratorB<>(new SimpleConstraint()));
boolean value = constraint.check(classToCheckA, classToCheckB);
```

Or:

```
Test classToCheckA = new Test("testA");
// TestB does implement the same interfaces as Test
TestB classToCheckB = new TestB("testB");
// TestC does implement the same interfaces as Test
TestC classToCheckC = new TestC("testC");

IConstraint<Test> constraint = new DecoratorA<>(new DecoratorB<>(new SimpleConstraint()));
boolean value = constraint.check(classToCheckA, classToCheckB, classToCheckC);
```

I tried using `varargs`, `Lists` or `Object[]` instead of the `T` from the  `check(obj:T)` but then I always need casts and a lot of exception handling (e.g. the number of input parameter need to be correct), so I was not satisfied.

The following code is one example what I tried. Like you see in the `SimpleConstraint` the `check` method only the type (`Test`) is allowed.

```
public interface IConstraint<T extends ICheckable> {
    public boolean check(T[] checkable);
}

public class SimpleConstraint implements IConstraint<Test> {
    @Override
    public boolean check(Test[] checkable) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is not possible with the above code:

```
Test classToCheckA = new Test("testA");
// TestB does implement the same interfaces as Test
TestB classToCheckB = new TestB("testB");
IConstraint<Test> constraint = new DecoratorA<>(new DecoratorB<>(new SimpleConstraint()));
boolean value = constraint.check(classToCheckA, classToCheckB);
```

Is there some improvement of the design so that different number of input parameters and different types can be supported?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "but then I always need casts and a lot of exception handling" ? I know, that it would make the question a lot longer, but you should provide a code - if someone wants to try, he/she doesn't need to create his/her own...

Comment: @Betlista I have not fully implemented the solution with `varargs`, `Lists` or `Object[]` so the code would not be runnable.

Comment: @Betlista I added some example code.

Comment: Since you are using generics, you should not use arrays. Please can you show what you tried with `List`, along with the specific (compiler?) errors you saw.

Comment: "e.g. the number of input parameter need to be correct" You can't check this generically. If you want to have specific numbers of parameters, enforced at compile time, you need separate constraint interfaces: `Constraint1`, `Constraint2`, `Constraint3` etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner okay but then I also need the same for the `Decorator` and I am afraid that there are a lot of base classes around when i have up to three different input parameters ...

Comment: @KevinWallis those are your choices: extra code to enforce it at compile time; or extra casts and checks to enforce it at runtime.

Comment: @AndyTurner okay but what would be the better approach?

Comment: @KevinWallis "better" is a subjective judgement that only you can make, depending upon your exact circumstances. I think that compile-time enforcement is best when possible, but if that makes the code an unmanageable rats' nest, then it's not a good approach.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks. At the beginning I thought there is maybe some `java` special which can help me and I don't know :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code above, the problem is, that Test and TestB does not have common ancestor...

```
IConstraint<Test> constraint = ...
boolean value = constraint.check(classToCheckA, classToCheckB);
```

You can make that work if `TestB extends Test` or other way around.

Better approach would be to have

```
IConstraint<ICheckable> constraint =
```

Comment: Yes but than I need to cast in the `constraint` itself.