# java ArrayList extends

Tags: java, arraylist, extends

I have the following extended classes and ArrayList fields:

```
class Fruit { }

class Banana extends Fruit { }

class FruitVendor {
 ArrayList<Fruit> fruits;
}

class BananaVendor extends FruitVendor {
  ArrayList<Banana> fruits;
}
```

I'm trying to declare methods for FruitVendor that handle fruits. for FruitVendor I want it to handle Fruit fruits, while for BananaVendor I want it to handle Banana fruits. I tried several approaches but so far I always end up with errors.

What are the possibilities/alternatives?

Comment: what did you mean, it is unclear what you try to archive!!?

Comment: Just a tip, use Interfaces where possible, i.e. `List<Banana>` instead of `ArrayList<Banana>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do!

Comment: what you are asking is not clear. your question title 'java ArrayList extends' doesn't goes with what you are asking. Try to specifically describe what exactly is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using generics:

```
public class FruitApp {

    class Fruit {
        public String toString() {
            return "fruit";
        }
    }

    class Banana extends Fruit {
        public String toString() {
            return "banana";
        }
    }

    class Vendor<T extends Fruit> {
        List<T> fruits;

        Vendor() {
            fruits = new ArrayList<T>();
        }

        void doSomethingWithMyFruit() {
            for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
                System.out.println("I'm a " + fruit.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FruitApp app = new FruitApp();
        app.createVendors();
    }

    private void createVendors() {
        Vendor<Fruit> vendor1 = new Vendor<Fruit>();
        vendor1.fruits.add(new Fruit());
        vendor1.fruits.add(new Banana());
        vendor1.doSomethingWithMyFruit();

        Vendor<Banana> vendor2 = new Vendor<Banana>();
        // vendor2.fruits.add(new Fruit()); compile error
        vendor2.fruits.add(new Banana());
        vendor2.doSomethingWithMyFruit();
    }

}
```

which outputs:

```
I'm a fruit
I'm a banana
I'm a banana
```

Of course, this assumes `doSomethingWithMyFruit()` is the same for all types of `Fruit`.  If that is not true then possibly combine with the [decorator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804192/decorator-pattern-with-multiple-generics).

Comment: I feel this is close, but I would also want BananaVendor, AppleVendor and MangoVender to, besides a shared identical doSomethingWithMyFruit(), have separate individual methods such as makeBananaPie() or makeAppleSauce(). It don't want an AppleVendor to have access to makeBananaPie().

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted like this:

```
class FruitVendor {
    List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

    void eatFruit() { 
       Fruit fruit = fruits.get(0);
       fruit.eat();
    }
}

class BananaVendor extends FruitVendor {
    void addBanana() { 
        fruits.add(new Banana());
    }

    void makeBananaPie() { 
        Banana banana = (Banana) fruits.get(0);
        banana.useInBananaPie();
    }
}
```

I think this might only work because I can guarantee by design that BananaVendor will only add Bananas to fruits.

I would be interested to know if anyone can see problems with this approach?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to have multiple fruit vendors that handle their fruits differently, you could make `FruitVendor` an abstract class with an abstract method `handleFruits` and then implement that method in your actual fruit vendors

FruitVendor

```
public abstract class FruitVendor {

    List<Fruit> fruits;

    public abstract void handleFruits(); 

}
```

BananaVendor

```
public class BananaVendor extends FruitVendor {

    List<Banana> fruits;

    @Override
    public void handleFruits() {
        // do something with bananas
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't make a non-generic `FruitVendor` and `BananaVendor` instead of `Vendor<T extends Fruit>`

Comment: Don't tell me what I can't do

Comment: My goal is to not have to copy/paste handleFruits() to BananaVendor, AppleVendor, MangoVendor etc. I want all these classes to reuse FruitVendor 's handleFruits() having it affect their own List<Banana>, List<Apple> and List<Mango>.